# AppBar wrong height

Tags: android, xml, android-appbarlayout, appbar

My AppBar is doing weird things.
This is what it looks like on a 720x1280 screen:
[image]

It is how it's supposed to look like. And this is how it looks like on a 1080x1920 screen:
[image]
I was playing around with the toolbar height in the app_bar_main.xml, but I didn't like it, so I set it back to the default ?attr/actionBarSize value. What could be the problem? Here is my app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.koostamas.justtry.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
    </FrameLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="@color/busblue"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove the height and width attribute from your include layout code

Comment: That solves the height, but then the navigation drawer and the fragment below the appbar disappears and only a white background is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try update your code. As of me this issue is with your views.Your approach is not correct to add this. If you are including the Toolbar only then whats the need of `coordinateLayout` and `AppBarLayout`!

update `app_bar_main.xml` ocde with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

update your `activity_main.xml` code with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/busblue"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If I include it like you said the appbar is behind the fragment below it, and if I move the include outside the drawerlayout (beacuse I want the navigation drawer to start below my appbar) then it looks the same as before.

Comment: ok i will update one more xml, do one thing exclude these above xml's and  conclude that one only

Comment: I got it. The xml you posted wasn't right, but you wrote that I don't need the CoordinatorLayout and you were right. That solved it. Thanks. Please update the post, so if anybody else needs the answer it will be clear.